# phpunit check logs file

Tags: php, testing, phpunit

I have several integration tests with phpunit,
and in the proccess of the tests there are some logs written to files in the system.

I would like to check if a line was written during a test, is that possible?

example:

```
/** @test */
function action_that_writes_to_log() {
    $this->call('GET', 'path/to/action', [], [], $requestXml);

    //I want this:
    $this->assertFileHas('the log line written', '/log/file/path.log');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**The obvious way:**

Implementing a custom assertion method, like the one you propose: `assertFileHas`. It's quite easy, just check if the string appears in the file. The problem you can get is that the line can already exist from another test or the same test already run. A possible solution for this is deleting the logs content before each test or test class, depending on your needs. You would need a method that deletes the logs and call it from `setUp` or `setUpBeforeClass`.

**I would go with another approach**: mocking the logging component, and checking that the right call is being done:

```
$logger_mock->expects($this->once())
             ->method('log')
             ->with($this->equalTo('the log line written'));
```

This makes easy to test that the components are logging the right messages, but you also need to implement a test that verifies that the logger is capable of actually writting to the file. But it's easier to implement that test once, and then just check that each component calls the logging method.